There is something wrong with my wallet
I currently have 1,557,166BTC=27.841,23 dollars. And I have a transfer right now at Blockchain. And this is like the sixth time, in the last two months, that I've had a transfer, and was unable to receive none of it. And this withdrawal will be my very first, and I have a back payment that they have been trying to help me complete. But I am unable to because, Everytime I scan the QR code to send the $65 in Bitcoin, whenever the next page pulls up there is always a message at the bottom of the page, that says, I don't have enough coins in the account. And it suggests that I input other numbers. But no matter what I try to do? Nothing ever works no matter what I input? And because I have been unable to withdrawal the funds, now I'm in jeopardy of my account being terminated and I just don't know what to do? I have reached out to the people that has tried to reminds me to make the withdrawal. And I've been in contact with them through email, and I've tried to let them know that my side of my account does not reflect the amount, that I'm told that I have.(1,557,166BTC) Once I scan the QR code the message appears and there is nothing that I can do. I'm in jeopardy of losing my account because I have been unable to complete the withdrawal. I really need some help. I have a transfer right now at Blockchain and I have about 24 hours left to complete the withdrawal, and if I can't withdrawal the funds within the last 24 hours, I just might lost the money and account. I really don't know who to talk to? Who to ask? It what to do? Can someone please help me? Or give me some advice that can and will solve my issue, so I can receive my Blessing? Thanks

Does this answer your question? Is it normal to be asked for an advance fee on a withdrawal?

Have you checked the balance of your address on the block chain ?
